# Magento Table Rates

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, csv, table-rates

I was wondering if there was a way to name the different table rates? I have set by importing a CSV with the different rates + the country codes and I would like to give some of these methods names for collection options for within the UK.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You mean shipping label?

Comment: I builded a module that does that and more